# Stuck in Code for BFS(breadth first search)

Tags: java, algorithm

I dont know why the output of this program is not proper.
Its just printing first visited node.AS far as i know the algorithm is correct.
Please help me finding the error.
THanks

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class bfs {
    static void bf(int v,int []vis,int n,int [][]a){
     int []q;
     int u;
     int f=0,r=-1;
     q=new int[20];
     q[++r]=v;
     vis[v]=1;
     while(f<=r){
        u=q[f];
        System.out.println(u);
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(a[u][i]==1&&vis[i]==0){
                q[++f]=i;
                vis[i]=1;
            }
        }   
        f++;
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] args){
    int []vis=new int [20];
    int [][]a=new int [20][20];
    int source,n;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of vertex");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the adjacency matrix");
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
        vis[i]=0;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the source vertex\n");
    source=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Nodes reached from "+source+"\n");
    bf(source,vis,n,a);
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the proper output?  You should post your input test case and desired output. As stated in the guides, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `q[++f]=i;` should be `q[++r]=i;`, which is trying to append new node to the end of the array(as it is used as a queue in BFS), not the front.